# Get executed sql statement in pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am executing a query that is invalid, but I'd like to be able to see **exactly** what the query is being executed by `pymysql` to debug it. Is there a way to do something like:

```
try:
    self.cursor.execute(SQL, tuple(PARAMS))
except:
    print (self.cursor.last_executed_statement) # ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-statement.html), you should be able to do:

```
print (self.cursor.statement)
```

> This read-only property returns the last executed statement as a string. The 
>    `statement` property can be useful for debugging and displaying what was sent to the MySQL server.
>
> The string can contain multiple statements if a multiple-statement string was executed. This occurs for execute() with multi=True. In this case, the `statement` property contains the entire statement string and the `execute()` call returns an iterator that can be used to process results from the individual statements. The `statement` property for this iterator shows statement strings for the individual statements.

Comment: thanks, yea unfortunately sometimes it doesn't even get that far! For example, sometimes it will give me a string-formatting error before it even tries to execute the SQL, so that's a bit trickier to debug when things are so abstracted...

Comment: The documentation you  linked to is MySQL not pymysql.  I can't find any documentation on the statement property of the Cursor object in Python.

Answer (score 2):

[pep 0249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/) defines no way to do that. But pymysql has a [`mogrify`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.mogrify) method that will show the generated SQL.

```py
values={ 'qty': 10, 'descr': "chocolate cake" }
sql='''INSERT INTO mywishes
       ( quantity, description )
       VALUES ( %(qty)s, %(descr)s )
    '''

try:
  cursor.execute( sql, values )
except pymysql.ProgrammingError:
  print("Hum, there is an error in the sql...")
  print(cursor.mogrify(sql, values))
```

Also note that if you don't get that far, it means pymysql can't map your SQL text and parameter to an actual SQL statement. This can happen for example if  your param list is too long or too short. The following will raise a TypeError:

```py
sql="insert into mywishes ( quantity, description ) values ( %s, %s )"
cursor.mogrify(sql, [1])
cursor.mogrify(sql, [1,2,3])
```